# "Error 'Cannot set properties of undefined' al intentar actualizar el título de una lista en mi clon de Trello con React"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined, material-ui, trello

Estoy construyendo un clon de Trello utilizando React y Material-UI. En mi aplicación, estoy intentando permitir que los usuarios actualicen el título de una lista. Sin embargo, estoy encontrando un error que no puedo resolver.

Estoy utilizando el patrón de Context API para administrar el estado y compartir la función de actualización del título entre componentes. Aquí está cómo tengo configurados los componentes relevantes:

componente app.js

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
import './App.css';
import { AddCardorList } from './components/AddCardorList';
import TrelloList from './components/TrelloList';
import mockData from './mockdata';
import { useState } from 'react';
import ContextAPI from './ContextAPI'
function App() {
  const classes = useAppStyle();
  const [data, setData] = useState(mockData);
  console.log(data)
  const updateListTitle = (updatedTitle, listId) => {
    const list = data.lists[listId]
    list.title = updatedTitle;
    setData({
      ...data,
      lists:{
        ...data.lists,
        [listId]: list
      }
    });
  }
  return (
    <ContextAPI.Provider value ={{updateListTitle}}>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <div className={classes.container}>
          {
            data.listIds.map(listID => {
              const list = data.lists[listID]
              return <TrelloList list={list} key={listID}></TrelloList>
            })
          }
          <AddCardorList type='list'></AddCardorList>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ContextAPI.Provider>
  );
}
export default App;
```

componente ListTitle.js

```
import { makeStyles, Typography, IconButton, InputBase } from "@material-ui/core";
import MoreHorizIcon from '@mui/icons-material/MoreHoriz';
import { useContext, useState } from "react";
import ContextAPI from "../ContextAPI";
export const ListTitle = ({ title, listId }) => {
    const {updateListTitle} = useContext(ContextAPI)
    const classes = useListTitleStyle();
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [newTitle, setNewTitle] = useState(title);
    const handleBlur = () => {
        //actualiza title del mockdata por newtitle
        updateListTitle(newTitle, listId)
        setOpen(false)
    }
    return (
        <>
            {open ?
                (
                    <InputBase
                        value={newTitle}
                        onChange={(e) => setNewTitle(e.target.value)}
                        onBlur={handleBlur}
                        autoFocus
                        fullWidth
                        inputProps={{ className: classes.input }}
                    />
                ) :
                (
                    <div className={classes.title}>
                        <Typography className={classes.titleText} onClick={()=>setOpen(true)}>
                            {title}
                        </Typography>
                        <IconButton>
                            <MoreHorizIcon />
                        </IconButton>
                    </div>
                )}
        </>
    )
}
```

Mi problema es que cuando intento actualizar el título de una lista en handleBlur, recibo un error "Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'title')". He revisado mi código varias veces y no puedo entender por qué estoy obteniendo este error.

Al cerrar la ventana de error y volver a abrir la aplicación, puedo ver que el cambio en el título se ha realizado correctamente, pero no se refleja en mockData. Parece que el cambio solo está ocurriendo en el estado local.

He verificado las propiedades que se pasan a updateListTitle y he utilizado console.log para rastrear los valores, pero aún no puedo encontrar la causa exacta del error.

¿Alguien podría ayudarme a entender qué está causando este error y cómo puedo solucionarlo? Agradezco cualquier sugerencia o consejo que puedan ofrecer. ¡Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Bienvenid@ a la comunidad, verifica que list `const list = data.lists[listId]` no este llegando `undefined` agrega un `console.log(list)` justo debajo de esa línea y comenta tus resultados

Comment: Gracias! el console me trae el objeto bien. ahi estuve viendo y pareciera ser que mi el problema esta en el acceso al title...